# Symfony 1.4 - Updating hidden value when form is updated

Tags: php, symfony1, propel, symfony-1.4

I am trying to modify the default value of a form field every time the form is updated. I have tried to edit the **$form->bind** in my processForm (..) but I am unsure how to do so.

Is it possible to get some example code or any approaches to do?

*The field name is 'processed' and I am trying to set the value to 'false' - Using Symfony 1.4 (Propel)*

Comment: Please give us more information on what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In the action, you can directly modify the values from the request before binding them to the form:

```
$parameters = $request->getParameter('nameofyourform');
$parameters['fieldyouwanttochange'] = 'newvalue';
$yourform->bind($parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you may modify the doSave() method of your form as suggested by the symfony team.

> If you need to modify the saving process itself, sfFormObject::doSave() is usually the best place to do it.

- http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms#chapter_06_saving_object_forms

The advantage of this solution is you have all your code related to the form in one class/file.